# Representation of the cyclic group $\mathcal{C}_4$.

Tags: representation-theory

So I was ill last week and as a result missed a lecture on Representation Theory.

As I am catching up with the notes now, I have stumbled onto this example which I didn't quite get.

**Example.** The representation of $\mathcal{C}_4=\langle x: x^4=e\rangle$ is given by $$\rho_8(e)=\begin{pmatrix}
1 &0 \\ 
0 &1 
\end{pmatrix},\quad \rho_8(x)=\begin{pmatrix}
i &0 \\ 
0 &-1 
\end{pmatrix},\quad \rho_8(x^2)=\begin{pmatrix}
-1 &0 \\ 
0 &1 
\end{pmatrix},\quad \rho_8(x^3)=\begin{pmatrix}
-i &0 \\ 
0 &-1 
\end{pmatrix},$$ which then concludes with computing the characters of each of these matrices which is fine.

But what I am wondering is where did the matrices come from, as in, what set is this acting on? The first rows of each of these matrices looks familiar as they look like they form the fourth roots of unity but I am not sure where the second rows come from.

Any clarification would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your question "where did the matrices come from, as in, what set is this acting on?" the answer is that they are $2\times 2$ matrices with complex entries and so they act on $\mathbb{C}^2$ linearly. The representation given by the matrices is reducible. In fact, since they are diagonal matrices, this representation is the direct sum of two other representations. One from the first rows, as you noticed yourself, and another from  the second rows. The first representation maps $x$ to $i$ and the second maps $x$ to $-1$. The two representations are of degree $1$ and hence are irreducible.